# how to check if a div has the same text as another div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble checking if a div has the same text as another div in jQuery

here's what I mean

**if div1 has the text hi
and div2 also has hi
then div2 should be removed**

here's my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Duplicated div should be removed -->

<div>Java</div>
<div>C#</div>
<div>Python</div>
<div>Java</div>
```

thanks,

Arnav

Comment: There's no code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a simple `reduce`:

```js
$(() => {
  [...$('div')].reduce(
    (a, e) => {
      if (a[e.textContent]) e.replaceWith('')
      else a[e.textContent] = !0
      return a
    }, {}
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Duplicated div should be removed -->

<div>Java</div>
<div>C#</div>
<div>Python</div>
<div>Java</div>
```

Comment: Great snippet, very fancy!

Answer (score 2):

You can establish this by simply doing the following

```js
var itemsFound = [];
$("div.item").each(function(index) {
 if(itemsFound.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
   $(this).remove()
  } else {
   itemsFound.push($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">Java</div>
<div class="item">C#</div>
<div class="item">Python</div>
<div class="item" value="abc">Java</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let arrayItems = [];
let arrayNames = [];
$('div').each(function(e){
   if(!arrayNames.includes($(this).text())){
      arrayNames.push($(this).text());
      arrayItems.push(this);
   }
});
```

You can see result with `console.log` will be have three items

console.log(arrayItems, arrayNames);

Comment: Add a snippet or a jsfiddle please